# Unable to install python-docx on WIndows

Tags: python-docx

I did C:\ Python27\mystuff\python-docx-0.8.5\pip install python-docx
Getting errors as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For your first query:

1. Open cmd as admin.
2. Goto `C:\Python27\Scripts`
3. Type: `pip install python-docx`

This should do the trick.

For your second query(pip problems)
1. I would advice you to reinstall your pip: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall` (After going to above specified folder)

Note: This will not affect your existing packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python-docx using the pip tool.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/
First download pip from the above link and extract into C:\pip

Then try installing python docx from the below link using `pip install python-docx` from c:\pip directory.

http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/install.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: HI Milind, When i try to install pip it says that you are using pip 7.1.2. In order to upgrade use 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' . When I do it, it says 'cannot import name PyPI; pip is a package and cannot be directly executed'.  I also get the same error for 'python -m pip install -U pip'

Comment: Can you also tell me where should the python-docx tar file be located?

Answer (score 0):

Download the python-docx package from this link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx

Then go to the Download folder in cmd: pip install package-name

If your inside proxy, remember to set it.